# Problem with binary decision variable on CPLEX

Tags: variables, cplex

Cplex must determine this binary decision variable: dvar boolean y[I][J][M]; // y(jm)=1 if operation O (ij) is assigned to machine m belonging to M (O(ij)) where int num_job=...; range J=1..num_job; //index job j
int num_operationsjob=...; range I=1..num_operationsjobj; //index operations

The problem is with M because I have to define the set of machines associated with O (ij) which I have now defined simply with M but it is wrong. I thought about defining them like this:

int machine [I][J] =...;

but now I don't know how to put it inside the decision variable. Do you have any ideas for me? Thank you :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

within [Making optimization simple](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-decision-optimization-simple-alex-fleischer/) see

array variable indexer size - 3 ways : [union](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooarrayvariableindexerunion.mod) , [tuple set](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooarrayvariableindexertupleset.mod), [decision expression](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooarrayvariableindexerdexpr.mod)

Comment: Just to add a bit more info to Alex's answer, I'd usually suggest using sets of tuples for indexing things. Having implemented many models over the years this has proven to be the most flexible and simple to use once you understand the idea; and because you can use the same approach in many cases, it becomes a familiar pattern which is both expressive and readable.

Comment: I tried to do it but I still have the problem with the decision variable: tuple infooperazioni {
   key int job;
   key int operazione;
   key int macchina;
   key int processamento;
   key int operatore;
 }
 {infooperazioni} operazioni =...;
 {int} jobs = {i.job|i in operazioni};
 {int} op = {i.operazione|i in operazioni};
 {int} macchine [o in op][j in jobs] = {i.macchina|i in operazioni : i.operazione ==o || i.job ==j};
dvar boolean y[I][J][m in macchine [o][j]] where I and J are the ones I wrote above. I know writing [m in macchine [o][j]] not good but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: The simplest way (not the most clever one) is https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooarrayvariableindexerunion.mod . So in your case you replace [m in macchine [o][j]] by allmachines where {int} allmachines={macchine[o][j] | o on op,j in jobs};

Comment: I write:  {int} allmachines= {macchine[o][j] | o in op,j in jobs}; but clpex get this error: "Cannot use type {int} as set item"